# What is the terminology for nonlinear terms that aren't cross terms?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology

Suppose we have a function f(x,y) that is defined this way:
$$
f(x,y) = ax + by + cxy + \frac{dxy}{1+ex+fy}
$$
Then the first two terms would be linear first-order terms, and the third term will be a second-order cross term. This terminology comes from polynomial approximation, if I'm not mistaken.

But what if my multivariable is *not* from a polynomial, like the fourth term? That is the more general situation for a two-dimensional function. The problem is that I do not have a good word for it. Most connotations for "multivariate" or "multivariable" are connected to functions that are actually linear/polynomial in each variable (e.g. $d=0$ in my example).

For my specific case, I want to emphasize that the term I am describing is complicated because it's not linear and it's not a cross term. It's simply a complicated function involving two variables.

Do you know a word that is commonly used to describe this kind of multivariate term?

Comment: There's no general terminology. Your particular term is a rational function, even given the $xy$ in the numerator (which is allowed in multivariate polynomials).